# Should I disable roaming profile on windows 10 if I only one have computer?

Tags: windows-10

I only have one computer on my wifi- at least one PC that has windows 10 and I noticed a lot of my files get saved to my roaming profile. I'm just learning what all these things are as I'm trying to understand the tech world, but I know that roaming profiles are for being able to access files from any computer on a given network (hence, roaming). I only have this one PC with windows installed and don't plan on having more. I'm not even sure I'd be able to access them if I got another because the wifi network would probably not automatically configure itself as the kind of network that supports this functionality I imagine- although if I did get a second computer, that could actually be a useful feature and I could learn something about setting up networks. But say I wanted to get a second computer just to mess around with, try risky things, potentially even destroy- so that I don't want to put sensitive data on it. I'm sure this could open up security risks and defeat the purpose of getting a second computer for that purpose.

Anyway my main question is that since it's just this one computer for now, would it be of any benefit to disable the roaming profile if possible, or steer Microsoft to saving files elsewhere. I noticed a file I was looking for was saved there, after doing a file explorer search for it. I guess I'm just trying  to understand the logic, the default and the optimization.

Comment: Let’s start by clarifying terms. What is it that you are calling “roaming profile?” The classic definition of roaming profiles is something used on a business network, it’s not something you would have or could use on your home computer. In order to help we need to know what you are actually talking about.

Comment: If you're just taking about the `AppData\Roaming` folder, files stored there are ones that *can* roam. They *don't* roam unless you set up an AD network *and* explicitly enable roaming. Otherwise, don't worry about it - the separation is only there for consistency and you have nothing to gain (and a lot to lose) by changing anything.